# Where can I save a CSV file that I construct dynamically to make it available for download?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, files

I dynamically construct a CSV file following that method:

```
$fp = fopen('export.csv', 'w');
foreach ($export as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

A file 'export.csv' appears in the very root of my Drupal directory.

I display a link to a page, allowing user to download that CSV file:

```
drupal_set_message(l('Export to CSV', 'export-csv'));
```

In the page callback function, I make the file downloadable like this:

```
function grap_contact_export_csv_page() {
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grape-export.csv\";" );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  $fp = fopen('export.csv', 'r') or die('Cannot access the file');
  echo fread($fp, filesize('export.csv'));
  fclose($fp);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

That works well.

What disturbs me is the location of the file. Of course, I know that I should not save it there. My question is: Where is the optimal location to save that kind of files? In the custom module's directory? In `sites/default/files`? **What is the best practice?**

Comment: Please read about [`file_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) and [`file_unmanaged_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7) and reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to use Drupal functions, not direct PHP functions, if there is Drupal API available. Particularly, here you may be interested in [`file_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) and [`file_unmanaged_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7).

If you want file available for short time, unmanaged file may be the way to go. But if you want periodic exports, archiving of prepared files, automatic clean-up etc, Managed is the way to go. If in doubt, try managed.

[Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) offers a pretty good [file_example.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/file_example!file_example.module/7), read it, play with it, and come back with more specific question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at file_save_data because I'm sure that it is something ephemeral and I don't need a database entry for that. I'll check your answer as soon as I succeed in my code ;-)

Comment: @Djouuuuh if in doubt, go managed. That's why **unmanaged** have additional word in function name, and managed does not.

Comment: I said the exact contrary that I wanted to say ^^ I meant unmanaged of course. I have no doubt about the file availability. Thanks again @Molot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save the file.

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; utf-8');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename = file_name.csv');

// print directly to stdout
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($export as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);

drupal_exit();
```

Comment: Without saving, things like download pausing, or resuming download after error, may fail. Or trigger regeneration of a file. Both results are not good.